# R Single sample K-S Test

Tags: r

This site gives a great example on how to execute a [two-sample K-S test](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kolmogorov-smirnov-test-in-r-programming/) in R

Upon reading the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dgof/versions/1.2/topics/ks.test), I'm completely lost about how I can execute a single sample K-S test. I understand that y can be "a numeric vector of data values, or a character string naming a cumulative distribution function or an actual cumulative distribution function such as pnorm. Alternatively, y can be an ecdf function (or an object of class stepfun) for specifying a discrete distribution."

I tried passing in one variable, got this error message: "argument "y" is missing, with no default"

Thinking about how pnorm can be used I recall this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/normal-distribution-in-r/). Not sure which one would be applicable in the case where I want to execute a single sample K-S test.

Comment: The K-S test of one sample against a distribution is a goodness-of-fit test. Something like `x <- rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 36); ks.test(x, pnorm, mean = 0, sd = 5)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thank you so much for your help!